# Maximum call stack exceeded when adding data to select2

Tags: jquery-select2

When trying to add data to a select 2 element after receiving it back from an ajax function I get this error on the console.

The data I get back from the server looks like this

```
[  
   {  
      "id":"55785510-2c64-447d-953d-01ce16ed9843",
      "text":"Room 100"
   },
   {  
      "id":"55785516-3da4-4791-98d5-01cd16ed9843",
      "text":"Room 110"
   },
   ...
]
```

It has a hand full of these items in the returned json.

Here I am trying to add the data to a select2 element that has been initialized already with no options added.

```
success: (data) ->
    console.log data
    $('select.building-select').select2
        data: data
```

As soon as I try to do that is when I get the call stack error

Here is the stack trace

```
Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
jQuery.extend.isPlainObject @ jquery.js:1
jQuery.extend.jQuery.fn.extend @ jquery.js:218
jQuery.extend.jQuery.fn.extend @ jquery.js:228
...
```

The thrid line repeats many times.

This error only happens when I attempt to add the data to the select on the success callback of the ajax function.

For reference here is the ajax function

```
$('#MeetingAddForm').find('input, select').change ->
    # If required inputs and selects for finding a meeting room are valid
    MeetingAttendants = $('#MeetingAttendants')
    MeetingDate = $('#MeetingDate')
    MeetingStartTime = $('#MeetingStartTime')
    MeetingEndTime = $('#MeetingEndTime')
    if MeetingAttendants.parsley().isValid() and MeetingDate.parsley().isValid() and MeetingStartTime.parsley().isValid() and MeetingEndTime.parsley().isValid()
        # All inputs are valid so lets get the available Room
        $.ajax
            url: $('#MeetingAddForm').data 'meetingrooms-ajax-url'
            data:
                attendants: MeetingAttendants.val()
                date: MeetingDate.siblings('input[type=hidden]').val()
                start_time: MeetingStartTime.siblings('input[type=hidden]').val()
                end_time: MeetingEndTime.siblings('input[type=hidden]').val()
            success: (data) ->
                console.log data
                $('select.building-select').select2
                    data: data
    else
        console.log 'false'
```

When I take the returned json and add it to a variable and attempt to assign the data to the select on page load, everything works fine.

Comment: Can you include a traceback (remove the repeating portions) of the stack error? This should include what triggered it, which is the key to solving the issue.

Comment: Updated original question with stack trace being thown

Comment: Is it stuck in a loop between `$.fn.extend` and `$.isPlainObject`? Your traceback is actually a bit short (it doesn't indicate the last area in Select2 code before it loops), and it's not actually clear what the repeating portion was..

Comment: I switched to a non minified version of jquery which is version `2.1.4` and updated the stack trace with what I'm seeing now, I can paste the relevant lines of code in the jquery.js file at those line numbers if necessary.

Comment: HI Jordan, same problem here, did you find a solution?

Comment: Yeah I think I ended up going with the other popular plugin that does this similar task. Don't remember, it's been a while and I have since moved jobs so I don't work on this project anymore ;P